# Connecting to dockerized Rethinkdb

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

Hello i am trying to connect to a `RethinkDB` container to no avail.I have downloaded the image and i can run it but it seems i cannot connect to it :

I am using:

`docker run --name rth -p 8100:8080 -d rethinkdb`

I have tried to connect to the browser client that exposes port `8080` to no avail.

**P.S** Knowing rethinkdb exposes a port for the `driver` and a port for the browser client i have also tried:
`docker run --name rth -p 27000:27015 -p 8100:8080 -d rethinkdb`
 .I tried connecting from the browser to both `27000` and `8100` and none work.What am i missing?
**P.S**
Using `docker logs rth` i get the following:

```
C:\Users\Adita>docker logs rth1
Recursively removing directory /data/rethinkdb_data/tmp
Initializing directory /data/rethinkdb_data
Running rethinkdb 2.3.6~0jessie (GCC 4.9.2)...
Running on Linux 4.9.93-boot2docker x86_64
Loading data from directory /data/rethinkdb_data
warn: Cache size does not leave much memory for server and query overhead (avail
able memory: 783 MB).
warn: Cache size is very low and may impact performance.
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080 ////-----!!!!!!!
Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.3
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.3
Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.3
Server ready, "3acef1c420d2_acx" b0adc99e-19a9-4780-b336-40c2e2b38a5f
```

As you can see `Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080` .Why can't i connect from the browser?

Comment: take a look at `docker logs`, are there any errors?

Comment: warn: Cache size does not leave much memory for server and query overhead (available memory: 783 MB). --- Try increasing the memory available to the docker host.

Comment: How are you actually trying to connect to it?  Are you using Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine (I see a "boot2docker" reference in the output)?

Comment: I have installed both docker toolbox but i run the containers using a docker-machine with virtual box.I thought they are complementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a config file "rethink.conf"

```
directory=/data/rethinkdb
log-file=/data/rethinkdb/log
bind=all
driver-port=28015
cluster-port=29015
http-port=8080
```

run the following command

```
docker run --name rethinkdb -d --net=host rethinkdb --config-file /path/to/rethinkdb.conf
```

go to http://localhost:8080

Comment: I get docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--config-file": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: missing permissions on the config file?

Comment: My issue was that I tried to include the host ip in the port mapping (as it was required for mongodb to publish the port through a firewall) -p {host_ip}:{port}:{port}. Removing the host_ip from the mapping resolved my issue and I do not need to use an extra config file.

Answer (score 1):

Rethink db runs n port 28015 and UI on 8080.

```
docker run -d -h `hostname` -p 8080:8080 -p 28015:28015 -p 29015:29015 -v <data-dir>:/data dockerfile/rethinkdb rethinkdb -d /data --bind all --canonical-address `curl icanhazip.com`
```

Rethinkdb UI must now be accessible from your host at http://loclahost:8080/

Comment: I have tried and it does not connect.I have tried connecting to `8080` from both the browser and `telnet`.

Comment: what you trying on browser, http://localhost:8080?
can you also check in your docker the output of command , ps aux | grep rethinkdb?

Comment: Yes i have tried both `127.0.0.1:8080` and `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Can you post output of ps aux| grep rethinkdb from your container to check if rethink db is running or not?

Comment: Just a note: For a mongodb container I used the port mapping -p {host_ip}:{port}:{port}. That did not work for rethinkdb. I had to remove the host_ip from the mapping: -p {port}:{port}, as already shown in the answer above.